# facebook account kit - Web Login settings error

Tags: facebook, account-kit

The following error message is being displayed

> "We're sorry, something went wrong."

while integrating with account kit for web (Javascript)

I am not also able to update Server URLs field under Web login setting section of the Facebook account kit product. When I click on Save changes button, it shows message as 'Saved' but it doesn't save the urls given in text field.

Is anyone else getting this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it is working now. actually i had to select domain name from popup box.

detailed report is here
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1190154747695673/

Answer (score 0):

You can file an issue with Facebook support here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/?tag_ids=1679169675664406. You specify more information about your setup and code samples to figure out what's going on there.